# Change message content in confirmation message prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I want to change the message content but i can't find it in the code or in the BO,
where i can find it or disable it ?
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question, but a usage one. You can start by looking at International->Translations and then the top entry allows you to modify the translations (and search for specific words to help locate it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the content of this mail is customizable from the International > Translations > Email translations page.

If you are talking about the underlined word "PrestaShop", this seems to be your Store name.
You can change it on the Shop parameters > Contact page, tab Stores.